# ngClass object syntax where class name is evaluated

Tags: angularjs

I have some text coming in from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {'text':'First text here', 'transition':'FadeIn', 'delay':1},
    {'text':'Second text here', 'transition':'FadeIn', 'delay':2}
]
```

These text blocks should animate in, with a delay that is specified by the delay property and a transition specified with the transition property.  I am using an ngRepeat. Originally I just used the enter/leave etc. on ngRepeat, but this text is bottom-aligned. When the second block comes in it shoves the first block up, which is not ideal.

What I want is something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="block in currentPage.textBlocks" ng-class="{block.transition:true, active:eventIndex>=$index}">block.text</li>
```

Note that I already have the model working to make this happen, and if I replace block.transition with 'FadeIn', it works. I'd really like to keep the ability to specify the transition through code, though, while solving the visual issue of the jumpy text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can see the Internet is clamoring to answer this one, but imma stop you right there.

What worked for me is class="{{block.transition}}" ng-class="{active:eventIndex>=$index}"